# Lightning component not being displayed after Template update

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I just updated my template from Napili winter  16 to Summer 16, but when I login in to the community the Home page component is redirected to Error page. It is showing as Invalid page.I will attach before and after upgrade links. All the components in that page are not showing at all.

Please let me know what has changed [image: Error page after update]

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in the console? Might require us to take a peek at this community - please let me know how I can help.